ASP.NET Core 8 Web API hosted in Azure App Service invoking third party/external API
Environment: ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, hosted in an Azure App Service invoking third party/external API.
In local environment, running in Visual Studio 2022, this is not an issue.
When an external/third party endpoint is invoked - a port number is incorrectly appended to the URL - this results in an error, the exception is:

No such host is known (testnomsapi.xyzxyz.com:443)

The code creates an instance of HttpClient in conjunction with HttpRequestMessage - this is in fact boilerplate code provided by the vendor whose service endpoint is being invoked.
There are no IP restrictions by the vendor for their test environment.
The Azure environment is provided the client - we are a service company providing an integration adapter API.
While the request object created in both environments - Local & DEV (Azure) appears to be the same, the one in Azure creates an endpoint that has the Port suffixed resulting in the error pasted above.
Grateful for any insight.
Thanks and regards,
Tried to delete the port number but the requestUri property is read only on the request object
Tried setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to development

Hi @z9998480, could you kindly check if any Networking settings in your app service?

And please also try to create a new app service in another region and try again, thanks

Port 443 is the default port for HTTPS. This should normally not affect the API call.
Can you perhaps provide the code that creates the HttpClient instance in conjunction with the HttpRequestMessage?

Please share your code repo.
